# Pandas for Aggregating Stats and Finding Max and Min Performers

Tags: python, pandas

I'm requesting help with a Pandas query to determine maximum and minimum performers by office.  An example of the data would look like:

```
OfficeNum   EmployeeNum ExcellentWriting    BadWriting  ExcellentEvidence   BadEvidence
100 34500   T   F   T   F
100 29991   F   T   T   F
100 10503   T   F   F   T
101 32451   T   F   F   T
101 55566   F   T   T   F
101 55566   F   T   F   T
101 64331   T   F   T   F
105 22661   F   T   T   F
105 23552   F   T   F   T
105 22661   T   F   T   F
105 69392   F   T   T   F
105 23552   F   T   F   T
```

Assuming that the columns above with "Excellent" are a positive (maximum) performance and "Bad" are negative (minimum), how could I aggregate the mean for each "Office" showing each each office's top and bottom performers.

For example, the requested output for maximum performing employees with their aggregated statistics (mean), based-on the data above, may look something like is:

```
OfficeNum   EmployeeNum ExcellentWriting    BadWriting  ExcellentEvidence   BadEvidence
100 34500   1   0   1   0
101 64331   1   0   1   0
105 22661   1   0   1   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assign numeric values based on `True 'Good'`, `True 'Bad'`, and `False`

   - `1, -1, 0` have been used as weights, however, any weight can be applied.
2. Groupby and sum based on Office and Employee Number
3. Get the row wise sum and the max sum for each office

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
data = {'OfficeNum': [100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101, 101, 105, 105, 105, 105, 105], 'EmployeeNum': [34500, 29991, 10503, 32451, 55566, 55566, 64331, 22661, 23552, 22661, 69392, 23552], 'ExcellentWriting': ['T', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F'], 'BadWriting': ['F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'T', 'T'], 'ExcellentEvidence': ['T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F'], 'BadEvidence': ['F', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'T']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get an array of good and bad columns
bad = df.filter(like='Bad').columns
exc = df.filter(like='Excellent').columns

# assign a numeric value for True Bad and True Good and False
df[bad] = df[bad].replace('T', -1).replace('F', 0)
df[exc] = df[exc].replace('T', 1).replace('F', 0)

# sum the values based on Office and Employee Number
s = df.groupby(['OfficeNum', 'EmployeeNum']).sum()

# return the rows and columns for the best performer
out = s.loc[s.sum(axis=1).groupby(level=0).idxmax()]

# display(out)
                       ExcellentWriting  BadWriting  ExcellentEvidence  BadEvidence
OfficeNum EmployeeNum                                                              
100       34500                       1           0                  1            0
101       64331                       1           0                  1            0
105       22661                       1          -1                  2            0
```

- In the case of Employee 22661 of Office 105

```py
105 22661   F   T   T   F
105 22661   T   F   T   F

105 22661   0   -1   1   0
105 22661   1    0   1   0

# column wise sum
105 22661   1   -1   2   0

# row wise sum
105 22661   2
```